# Translate VisuAlgo Bubble Sorting code to Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, do-while, bubble-sort

starting from the SORTING algorithm I found on this website (it's really cool, it let's you visualize algorithms while they are operating..), I wanted to translate their code [and I'm not sure what language it is..] to Javascript, and apply it to an Array of numbers to be sorted.

After many attempts, I still haven't sorted it out and my code is not providing the sorted Array.

- 1) Any suggestion on how to fix it?
- 2) I see the VisuAlgo code uses an `if` statement, within a `for` loop, within a `do-while` loop... is that possible in Javascript? To me it looks like an `if else` statement within the `do while` (see my actual code) could replace the `for`.

Thank you!

VisuAlgo code (https://visualgo.net/en/sorting):

```
do

  swapped = false

  for i = 1 to indexOfLastUnsortedElement-1

    if leftElement > rightElement

      swap(leftElement, rightElement)

      swapped = true

while swapped
```

My Code:

```
  function swap(element1, element2) {
    var t = element1;
    element1 = element2;
    element2 = t;
    return [element1, element2];
  };

  var startArray = [2, 1, 0, 5, 1];
  var swapped = true;

  do {
      for (i = 0; i < startArray.length; i++) {
        if (startArray[i] > startArray[i+1]) {
        swap(startArray[i], (startArray[i]+1));
        console.log(startArray);
        i++;
      } else {
      swapped = false;
      }
    }
    }
  while (swapped);
  console.log(startArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

```
    swap(startArray[i], (startArray[i]+1));
```

is obviously incorrect. You probably meant

```
    swap(startArray[i], startArray[i+1]);
```

But I do not understand how use your swap code. What do you do with the values that are returned by this function?

Probably a better code would be

```
 [startArray[i], startArray[i+1]] = swap(startArray[i],startArray[i+1]));
```

You can also do the same thing in a more compact way

```
startArray[i]=[startArray[i+1], startArray[i+1]= startArray[i]][0];
```

I have not tested the code, but it should work.

And if your arrays are large, prefer insertion sort to bubble sort. It is generally faster and it is easy to implement.

Comment: thank you @Alain Merigot; added the 2 changes you mentioned, the result improved but still, I got only a partial sort. I took off i = 1 within the for loop and changed it with i = 0 and it worked out properly. I included the final code below for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Final Code:

```
function swap(element1, element2) {
    var t = element1;
    element1 = element2;
    element2 = t;
    return [element1, element2];
  };

  var startArray = [2, 1, 9, 5, 1, 4,7, 457, 653, 43, 3];
  var swapped = true;

  do {
      for (i = 0; i < startArray.length; i++) {
        if (startArray[i] > startArray[i+1]) {
        [startArray[i], startArray[i+1]] = swap(startArray[i],startArray[i+1]);
        console.log(startArray);
        i = 0;
      } else {
      swapped = false;
      }
    }
    }
  while (swapped);
  console.log(startArray);
```